# Does Nora know she killed a vampire?

Tags: being-human-us

> In the season premiere it's shown that Nora transformed into a wolf and killed Heggemann. Later on it shows that Nora actually remembers doing this.

Does she know that she killed a vampire though or does she think she killed a human that was trying to kill Josh?

Comment: You can hide the spoilers in >! markdown.  Separate the spoilers into their own paragraph, and put a >! at the start of that paragraph to mark it as a spoiler.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed to knw how to do spoilers, lucky I found this post! Thanks for this info! (to clarify, you need to type >! without any spaces in order to hide the spoiler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

She knows she killed a vampire. Remember that Werewolves have an exceptionally keen sense of smell, so they can detect whether a creature is a vampire or human, especially during the full moon when they are turned, and all their senses are heightened.

However, the show humanizes vampires, attempting to make the audience empathize with vampire deaths just as much as human deaths. That's why they have Josh say things like "I didn't want you to feel horrible, that's why I didn't tell you".

Comment: I know that werewolves can be smelled by vampires but I wasn't aware that the reverse was true also. Is it stated in any episode? Also is it stated anywhere that she knows it was a vampire for sure. I mean Josh doesn't even know that she remembers killing. And she wouldn't really be aware of any other vampires than Aidan.

Comment: Yes, later episodes confirmed this because Josh was like"You killed a vampire!" and Nora did not present any significant reaction, implying that she already knew. Although the show did not specifically show her saying a sentence that she knew it was a vampire, the show gives plenty of clues that allude to this fact, if you pay close attention. Hope this helps! Please accept if so.